# Background gradient repeating on page

Tags: html, css

I've tried numerous things and can't seem to get this background gradient to not repeat at the bottom like it is: [URL]

I can't think of anymore solutions.

Comment: What have you tried........and what do you have at the moment! You'd think after 366 questions, you'd know that this is not a helpful question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the following:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp

Comment: Ahh... interesting... I didn't realize that would work on Gradients.  So I should be able to set a background color and have the gradient fixed.  I see that... very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the CSS property [background-repeat](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-repeat)? You can set it so the background image repeats horizontally but not vertically:

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Answer (score 0):

simple remove all the actual background styling from the html and remove the class attribute from the html tag.  if you need to style something on the html just do it on the body aslo remove your height: 100% on the html tag.